# Format number between markers as subscript

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word, text-formatting

I would like to find a number between two hashtags, delete the hashtags and format the number that was between the hashtags as subscript.

Example: The text `##12##` should be converted to <sub>`12`</sub>.

Here is my code so far:

```
Public Sub SubscriptText()
    With Selection.Find
         .ClearFormatting
         .Text = "##"
         .Replacement.ClearFormatting
         .Replacement.Text = "##"
         .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
    End With
End Sub
```

This removes the `##`, but how do I format the number as subscript?

Comment: The best way would probably be to use a regular expression a.k.a. regex. [Search for examples to get you started.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[vba]+regex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this: look for the end of the opening hashtag, and the start of the closing hashtag. Everything between those two positions is presumably a number for which you want to change the font.

```
end of
opening
hashtag
    ꜜ
 # # 1 2 # # 
        ꜛ
     start of
     closing
     hashtag
```

This worked for me:

```
Dim wd As Document
Dim rOpeningHashtag As Range
Dim rClosingHashtag As Range
Dim rBewteenHashtags As Range
Dim hashtagFound As Boolean

Set wd = ActiveDocument
wd.Range.Select

Do
    'Look for opening hashtag
    hashtagFound = Selection.Find.Execute("##")
    If Not hashtagFound Then Exit Do 'end of document reached
    Set rOpeningHashtag = Selection.Range
    'Look for closing hashtag
    Selection.Find.Execute "##"
    Set rClosingHashtag = Selection.Range

    'Number is in between the two.
    Set rBewteenHashtags = wd.Range(rOpeningHashtag.End, rClosingHashtag.Start)
    rBewteenHashtags.Font.Subscript = True
    'Get rid of the opening and closing hashtags
    rClosingHashtag.Delete
    rOpeningHashtag.Delete
Loop
```

Comment: Very useful, thanks. I needed a `Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd` between the two searches, otherwise the second one would only search inside the found result of the first one.