# Delete text between parentheses if text between quotes has fewer than 3 words

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document with several paragraphs.  I would like to iterate through each paragraph of the document and check and see if there are words in quotes.  If there are less than 3 words in quotes I would like to delete all appearances of text within parenthesis.

So imagine the following paragraph.

> The information that you need to include depends on what type of source the material comes from. For "printed material", you normally only need to include the author **(s)** **(or article title if there is no author)** and year of publication **(never the month or day)** in your reference. When citing a specific part of a source **(for example, a direct quotation)**, you will also want to indicate the page number **(s)** or other designation **(chapter, figure, table, equation, etc.)**. For Internet sources, paragraph numbers can be used when page numbers are not available.

Since the phrase **"printed material"** only contains 2 words I would then like to delete all of the words that are in parenthesis and the parenthesis themselves.

How would I go about doing something like this using VBA in Microsoft Word? I have posted some of my failed code in an effort to show that this is a sincere question.

```
Sub RemoveUnnecesaryTexts()

Dim doc As Document
Dim para As Paragraph

Set doc = ActiveDocument

For Each para In doc.Paragraphs
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "(""<*>"")"
    End With

    If Selection.Find.Execute Then
        Selection.Parent.Select
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = "\((<*>)\)"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    End If
Next para

End Sub
```

This code isn´t checking for the word count in the quotations as I haven´t successfully gotten that far.  But at least it will give you an idea of what Iʼm trying to do.  Any ideas as to what I´m doing wrong here?

Comment: This question shows no research effort or attempt at self-help. You've been around for a while... You should know better than this?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I´m sorry if that´s how it appears to you.  Iʼve actually looked for quite some time and have been toiling on this problem for a number of hours.  I chose not to post the code from my failed attempts because I think that it could mislead potential responses since I really am lost here.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I have posted a sampling of my failed code that doesn´t work in an effort to show that I have indeed tried to research this issue.  I just don´t know where to go with it.

Comment: Ok. This may put you on the right track: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617920/format-number-between-markers-as-subscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building upon my earlier answer: [Format number between markers as subscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617920/format-number-between-markers-as-subscript/25618539#25618539)

This works for me:

```
Dim wd As Document
Dim para As Paragraph
Dim rOpeningQuote As Range
Dim rClosingQuote As Range
Dim rBewteenQuotes As Range
Dim quoteFound As Boolean
Dim nWordsBetweenQuotes As Long
Dim rOpeningParenthesis As Range
Dim rClosingParenthesis As Range
Dim openingParenthesisFound As Boolean

Set wd = ActiveDocument

For Each para In wd.Paragraphs
    para.Range.Select
    'Look for opening quote
    quoteFound = Selection.Find.Execute("""")
    If quoteFound Then
        Set rOpeningQuote = Selection.Range
        'Look for closing quote
        Selection.Find.Execute """"
        Set rClosingQuote = Selection.Range
        'Count words between the two
        Set rBewteenQuotes = wd.Range(rOpeningQuote.End, rClosingQuote.Start)
        nWordsBetweenQuotes = UBound(Split(rBewteenQuotes.Text, " ")) + 1

        If nWordsBetweenQuotes < 3 Then
            para.Range.Select
            Do
                'Look for opening parenthesis
                openingParenthesisFound = Selection.Find.Execute("(")
                If Not openingParenthesisFound Then Exit Do
                Set rOpeningParenthesis = Selection.Range
                'Look for closing parenthesis
                wd.Range(Selection.End, para.Range.End).Select
                Selection.Find.Execute ")"
                Set rClosingParenthesis = Selection.Range
                'Delete and select rest of paragraph for next iteration
                wd.Range(rOpeningParenthesis.Start, rClosingParenthesis.End).Delete
                wd.Range(Selection.End, para.Range.End).Select
            Loop
        End If
    Else
        'No quote found in this paragraph. Do nothing.
    End If
Next para
```

Result:

[image]

Note that deleting the bits in parentheses will leave multiple consecutive spaces behind (example highlighted in pink in image above). Not sure whether you want to fix that, but if so, have a shot at it and ask a new question if you're having trouble.

Comment: For some reason I get an error from time to time on the "quoteFound = Selection.Find.Execute("""")" line.The error says, The Replace With text contains a group number which is out of range.  I´ll be happy to post another question if you like.  :)

Comment: I got beyond this by running a blank Selection.Find before running your code.  Strikes me as a hack, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

pseudocode:

```
Iterate through the paragraphs. 
Regex Match the quoted sub string "...." and then count the spaces in the match
If spaces < 2 then 
    Second Regex match all occurrences of (....) and delete all matches in the paragraph 
Else 
    Continue to next paragraph
```

Note that this depends on only one quoted sub-string being present. If that's not the case, you'll have to implement logic to select the correct quotes.

Edit: I'm nowhere near a regex expert but the matches could be as simple as:

```
String match1 = "/".*/""
String match2 = "/(.*/)"
```

These will greedily match your intended patterns, meaning they will match "1", "12345", (123456....1223447748557), and also the empty string "" and empty parentheses (). If the empties are not desired then switch '*' with '+'.

I have not tested this, I just hack the regexes until they do what I want. Also, you need to either deal with (or ignore) parentheses that occur within quotes.

Also, for any language you choose to implement this in, you can either iterate through the matched quote sub string character by character and increment a counter if the character is a space, or, better: see if there's a function within your string library that will do this for you.

Finally, for some languages, you should have a String.replace() function, in which case I'd iterate through every parentheses match and feed the match into the function like this Paragraph.replace(matches[i], ""), which just replaces your match with an empty string.

Edit: 
Oh. I somehow missed the VBA part of the title. Then you'd need to deal with Word's object model. AFAIK there's a Document object that should return a Paragraph[] collection you can iterate over. I know VBA has a Regex class you can use, and the String methods should just work. Not sure if VBA has a 'int HowManyTimesDoesThisCharAppearInThisString(String search, char target)' but it wouldn't be that hard to implement it yourself. Could just look through the String docs over on MSDN. That's my only favorite thing about working with M$ code, there's a better than average chance someone else has had the same problem as you, and MSDN is pretty decently documented.

Also, I found this, may be helpful to you: [Counting the Words in a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16604179/counting-the-words-in-a-string)
That method is actually simpler, it just splits the string on spaces and counts the length of the resulting array.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer.  I understand conceptually how to make it happen I just am having difficulties making that concept come to life in VBA.

Comment: I can't comment on your main post, but I see that you've edited it.  Now I have more questions: why do you have < & > in the Regex, are you intentionally trying to match those characters? Second, and this is important, you don't have the '.' in the Regex, so unless I'm mistaken, that Regex matches this : "<<<<<>" but not this "I am a string". Also, and more importantly: when you say "it doesn't work", what exactly is happening.